# Obtaining trading days from rollapply in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, rollapply

I have following simulated dataset of y column with fixed trading days (say 250) of 2018.

```
data
# A tibble: 249 × 2
   Date                     y
   <dttm>               <dbl>
 1 2018-01-02 00:00:00  0.409
 2 2018-01-03 00:00:00 -1.90 
 3 2018-01-04 00:00:00  0.131
 4 2018-01-05 00:00:00 -0.619
 5 2018-01-08 00:00:00  0.449
 6 2018-01-09 00:00:00  0.448
 7 2018-01-10 00:00:00  0.124
 8 2018-01-11 00:00:00 -0.346
 9 2018-01-12 00:00:00  0.775
10 2018-01-15 00:00:00 -0.948
# … with 239 more rows
```

with tail

```
> tail(data,n=10)
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Date                       y
   <dttm>                 <dbl>
 1 2018-12-13 00:00:00 -0.00736
 2 2018-12-14 00:00:00 -1.30   
 3 2018-12-17 00:00:00  0.227  
 4 2018-12-18 00:00:00 -0.671  
 5 2018-12-19 00:00:00 -0.750  
 6 2018-12-20 00:00:00 -0.906  
 7 2018-12-21 00:00:00 -1.74   
 8 2018-12-27 00:00:00  0.331  
 9 2018-12-28 00:00:00 -0.768  
10 2018-12-31 00:00:00  0.649
```

I want to calculate rolling sd of column y with window 60 and then to find the exact trading days not actual-usual days (it can be done from index? I don't know.)

```
data2 = data%>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(Date))
data3=data2[,-1];head(data3)
roll_win = 60
data3$a = c(rep(NA_real_, roll_win - 1), zoo::rollapply(data3$y, roll_win ,sd))
dat = subset(data3, !is.na(a))
dat_max = dat[dat$a == max(dat$a, na.rm = TRUE), ]
dat_max$date_start = dat_max$date -  (roll_win - 1)
dat_max
```

Turn outs that the period of high volatility is :

```
dat_max
# A tibble: 1 × 4
      y date           a date_start
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>    
1 0.931 2018-04-24  1.18 2018-02-24
```

Now if I subtract the two dates I will have :

```
> dat_max$date - dat_max$date_start
Time difference of 59 days
```

Which is actually true but these are NOT THE TRADING DAYS.

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71171615/rollapply-in-r-time-frame-indexing/71171868?noredirect=1#comment125895688_71171868) but it didn't solved the problem.Actually the asked question then was how I can obtain the days of high volatility.

Any help how I can obtain this trading days ? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

FOR FULL DATA

```
library(gsheet)
data= gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PdZDb3OgqSaO6znUWsAh7p_MVLHgNbQM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109626011108852110510&rtpof=true&sd=true")
data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Start date for each time window

If the question is how to calculate the start date for each window then using the data in the Note at the end and a window of 3:

```
w <- 3
out <- mutate(data, 
  sd = zoo::rollapplyr(y, w, sd, fill = NA),
  start = dplyr::lag(Date, w - 1)
)
out
```

giving:

```
         Date        y        sd      start
1  2018-12-13 -0.00736        NA       <NA>
2  2018-12-14 -1.30000        NA       <NA>
3  2018-12-17  0.22700 0.8223515 2018-12-13
4  2018-12-18 -0.67100 0.7674388 2018-12-14
5  2018-12-19 -0.75000 0.5427053 2018-12-17
6  2018-12-20 -0.90600 0.1195840 2018-12-18
7  2018-12-21 -1.74000 0.5322894 2018-12-19
8  2018-12-27  0.33100 1.0420146 2018-12-20
9  2018-12-28 -0.76800 1.0361488 2018-12-21
10 2018-12-31  0.64900 0.7435068 2018-12-27
```

### Largest sd's with their start and end dates

and the largest 4 sd's and their start and end dates are:

```
head(dplyr::arrange(out, -sd), 4)
```

giving:

```
        Date      y        sd      start
8 2018-12-27  0.331 1.0420146 2018-12-20
9 2018-12-28 -0.768 1.0361488 2018-12-21
3 2018-12-17  0.227 0.8223515 2018-12-13
4 2018-12-18 -0.671 0.7674388 2018-12-14
```

### Rows between two dates

If the question is how many rows are between and include two dates that appear in data then:

```
 d1 <- as.Date("2018-12-14")
 d2 <- as.Date("2018-12-20")
 diff(match(c(d1, d2), data$Date)) + 1
 ## [1] 5
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "   Date                       y
 1 2018-12-13T00:00:00 -0.00736
 2 2018-12-14T00:00:00 -1.30   
 3 2018-12-17T00:00:00  0.227  
 4 2018-12-18T00:00:00 -0.671  
 5 2018-12-19T00:00:00 -0.750  
 6 2018-12-20T00:00:00 -0.906  
 7 2018-12-21T00:00:00 -1.74   
 8 2018-12-27T00:00:00  0.331  
 9 2018-12-28T00:00:00 -0.768  
10 2018-12-31T00:00:00  0.649"
data <- read.table(text = Lines)
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
```

Comment: No the question is how I can obtain the 60 dates that have the highest standard deviation.Not just the start.The specific dates.

Comment: Change w to 60.

Comment: I made an edit with the full data.Hope that can help

Comment: Alright.Probably I wasn't clear in my question.Let's me explain.The dataset has 250 observations.If you roll calculate the sd with window 60 in an object like `a=zoo::rollapply(y, 60 ,sd)`.Now if you take the `max(a)` you will find the maximum rolling sd.Now the question is: What the 60 days period that have this maximum sd?

Comment: Have moved comments to answer.

Comment: Is the first w elements of the  column Date of the out object